# Flash Game World Limits

Tags: flash, resolution, bounds

I am going to make platformer game on Flash using starling framework. I wont it to be a standalone version, installing version. Does anyone have any advices about that topic particularly I am interested in:

- How To Make Flash Project installable
- what resolution should i use? not to scale game on different monitors
- How big can flash world be, I mean in flash professional, max width can be 2880 pixels, is it possible to increase it? To make a long way for character, like in Game "Beep" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFxaovfxbnY&feature=related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Export it as an Adobe AIR project, which is installable.
2. Unless you're using sprites only, you'll want to keep the renderable area as small as possible to increase speed of the game. I like to keep under about 700x550. If you use a single `Bitmap` canvas and use `copyPixels()` through it's `bitmapData` property you'll be able to make it as large as you want without noticeable loss of speed.
3. A solution here could be to split your map up into segments - when you reach a given point in the current segment you can seamlessly reset your position back to 0 and replace the segment with a new one.